# How to Pause after animating in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

still learning to create simple animation with jquery. This one I'm doing right now is a div that slides to the left of its parent div continuously. I'm trying to make a pause after showing the child div for 2 sec and then repeat the animation again after a delay but I'm no good. Please help.

Please see my [code](http://codepen.io/ajnoguerra/pen/DcCsn)

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout to make a delay. 2000 is 2 second

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.slide-right').delay(5000).css({width:'0'}).animate({width:'100%'}, 800, reslide); 
}, 2000);
```

[Example here](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/CyKEj)

Answer (score 0):

Its to simple as do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    reslide();
});
function reslide(){
  $('.slide-right').delay(5000).css({width:'0'}).animate({width:'100%'}, 800, function(){
setTimeout(reslide, 2000);
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a litte easy example.

html:

```
<div id="slideRange">
    <div id="slideBox">woohoo</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#slideRange{
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

#slideBox{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    line-height:150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

js:

```
function mySlide() {
    var slideRange = parseInt($('#slideRange').css('width')) - parseInt($('#slideBox').css('width'));
    $('#slideBox')
    .animate({left: 0}, 500)
    .delay(500)
    .animate({left: slideRange}, 1000, function() {
        setTimeout(mySlide, 2000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    mySlide(10);
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/RUvZZ/